# Calling post method from another method in the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

This is the method I wanna call:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string MyPostMethod(int i)
    { ... }
```

I want to call it from another method in the same controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public string MyOtherMethod(int i)
    { MyPostMethod(i); }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat the controller methods as class methods .(A controller is just a class)

So would you do it for a class? If it is YES, you can do it for a controller too

Anyway, I would encapsulate the code in a private method and call it within the controller's

methods.

Comment: This is correct of course, but you could also `RedirectToAction` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I would use RedirectToAction to call an action in another controller to bring the routing values along the call.
You can use RedirectToAction to call a method in the same controller if you want to modify the routing values

Comment: @srcee : This action is simply a redirection. Not posting. You can just call RedirectToAction() method mentioning the method (action) you wanna call...